# How to make listbox placed in a large canvas in wpf more performant?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, listbox, virtualizingstackpanel

I have a custom `UserControl` looks like this:
[image]

The brown boxes are `ListBoxItem`s in a `ListBox` control and there are many such items. Each item again contains a lot of other controls, like images, text blocks among others. They and a `Rectangle` control are fixed positioned relative to a very big canvas, wrapped in a `ScrollViewer`. The rectangle takes up almost the entire height of the canvas. Currently, all the boxes are rendered at once, as can be confirmed in the visual tree (in the visual tree, there are 30k+ elements with about 40 elements per `ListBoxItem`), because the `ListBox` has a height of almost the canvas' height. However, the user can only see a small portion of all the boxes (and the rectangle) at one time. The user can scroll down to bring the boxes into view and the corresponding part of the rectangle. Since all the boxes are rendered at once, the `UserControl` behaves **very poorly** in terms of performance when a view containing this `UserControl` is being navigated to.

Apparently, the `ListBox` is not virtualized in this setup. I tried to limit the height of the `ListBox` to the containing `ScrollViewer`, and then virtualizing seems to be turned on. However now the `ListBox` itself has an implicit `ScrollViewer` in it. When the user scrolls the viewport down, the boxes corresponding to the certain part of the rectangle will **not** be shown.

The code I use to simulate this:

```
Window x:Class="ListBoxVirtualizationExample.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450">
    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <Canvas Width="2000"
                Height="2000">
            <Rectangle x:Name="Rect1"
                       Canvas.Left="0"
                       Canvas.Top="0"
                       Width="100"
                       Height="100"
                       Fill="Red" />
            <Rectangle x:Name="Rect2"
                       Canvas.Left="0"
                       Canvas.Top="600"
                       Width="100"
                       Height="100"
                       Fill="Green" />

            <ListBox Canvas.Left="150"
                     Width="200"
                     Height="{Binding Path=ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ScrollViewer}}}"
                     ItemsSource="{Binding YourDataSource}"
                     VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                     VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Standard">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Canvas>
                            <TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding RectangleLeft}"
                                       Canvas.Top="{Binding RectangleTop}"
                                       FontSize="20"
                                       Text="{Binding Text}" />
                        </Canvas>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Canvas>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Window>
```

code-behind:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace ListBoxVirtualizationExample
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            YourDataSource = new ObservableCollection<DataItem>();

            for (var i = 0; i < 200; i++)
            {
                YourDataSource.Add(new DataItem {Text = $"Item {i}", RectangleLeft = 0, RectangleTop = 20 * i});
            }

            DataContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<DataItem> YourDataSource { get; set; }
    }

    public class DataItem
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public double RectangleLeft { get; set; }
        public double RectangleTop { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This gives me results like this when scrolled down:

[image]

But ideally, it should look something similar to this (this picture is taken when the `ListBox` takes the entire height of the canvas, so basically no virtualization is on) :
[image]
That is, items 25-28 should always be in the green square no matter how the user changes the viewport and scrolls up and down.

The question is: how can I improve the performance of the `UserControl`? Is the `ListBox` control the right way to do this? Are there any other ways to achieve the same effect?

Comment: Try using Virtualized Canvas: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jgoldb/virtualized-wpf-canvas

Comment: What is your goal, why do you want to position the TextBlock elements on a Canvas?

Answer (score 0):

The virtualization is working. Because you wrap each item into a `Canvas` and apply the content position absolute, you are effectively moving the `TextBlock` elements out of the item container: each `TextBlock` is rendered on the screen relative to the `Canvas` (the one inside the `DataTemplate`).
Because you assigning them a `Canvas.Top` of a multiple of `20` the items are stacked by force and not by the `VirtualizingStackPanel` that the `ListBox` uses as panel.

If your idea was to add a top margin of `20` to each item, you must do this from the `ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`:

```xml
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,20,0,0" />
    </Style>
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
<ListBox>
```

If your idea is to place the `TextBlock` elements on a `Canvas` to position them by the location provided by the data item (and by stacking them inside the item panel), then instead of wrapping each item's content into a `Canvas` you must replace the panel of the `ListBox` with a `Canvas` and set `Canvas.Top` and `Canvas.Left` on the `ListBoxItem` (from the `ItemContainerStyle`). But unless you have acustom `Canvas` panel that supports virtualization you lose this performance feature.

The second issue is that your `ListBox` is obviously the wrong size. You give it the size of the `ScrollViewer` which is basically the size of the viewport.
If the `ListBox` is supposed to stretch across the `Canvas` you must bind it accordingly. Bind `ListBox.Height` to `Canvas.Height`.

The following code has removed the `Canvas` from the `DataTemplate` and fixed the binding set on the `ListBox.Height` property to make it behave as expected.

```xml
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
  <Canvas Width="2000"
          Height="2000">
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect1"
               Canvas.Left="0"
               Canvas.Top="0"
               Width="100"
               Height="100"
               Fill="Red" />
    <Rectangle x:Name="Rect2"
               Canvas.Left="0"
               Canvas.Top="600"
               Width="100"
               Height="100"
               Fill="Green" />

    <ListBox Canvas.Left="150"
             Width="200"
             Height="{Binding Path=Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}"
             ItemsSource="{Binding YourDataSource}">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock FontSize="20"
                     Text="{Binding Text}" />
        </DataTemplate>
      </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
  </Canvas>
</ScrollViewer>
```

Answer (score -1):

The first thing to try is give each item in that listbox a specific size.

Your listbox isn't virtualising because it doesn't have a size for each of it's items. They are all as big as they like because each item is going in a virtualising stackpanel and has nothing sets or constrains it's size.

If you give each item a size then the virtualising stackpanel can decide how many of them should fit and which will not.
That will of course virtualise those that do not fit.
You could do that with the canvas.

The height here is just arbritrary. You should pick whatever suits size of your rectangles. Maybe that's 50 * 1900. It's the height that matters, obviously.

```
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
              **    <Canvas Height="22" Width="200">  **
                        <TextBlock Canvas.Left="{Binding RectangleLeft}"
                                   Canvas.Top="{Binding RectangleTop}"
                                   FontSize="20"
                                   Text="{Binding Text}" />
                    </Canvas>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

I don't really follow why you have a canvas in each of the items though. It doesn't make much sense without an explanation. But maybe that doesn't matter so much.

If you can get the ui items down to around 10,000 then I think you'll likely find your problems greatly reduced.

If not then you could consider simplifying the controls in each item somehow. Difficult to say exactly what would be best without knowing more about the intent of this design.  A drawingvisual encapsulating everything in an item into one thing might be something to consider.

I don't really follow why the whole thing is not one listbox with a canvas as itemspaneltemplate and everything rendered from that. You would just have the one scrollviewer to deal with.

With this scenario the 2000 x 2000 canvas would be the panel in the listbox and everything would be rendered in that.

It would virtualise ( if you tell it how big things are ).